# Why can't I load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: maven, akka, slf4j

I'm following a video course in Akka, and can't get the logging to work. I use IntelliJ. I have tried a little with different versions of slf4j...  and I have the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>AkkaPrime2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <akka.version>2.6.8</akka.version>
    <scala.version>2.13</scala.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor-typed_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-testkit-typed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor-testkit-typed_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And the code is using "normal" akka methods.

When the code has run:

```
.onAnyMessage(message ->{
  System.out.println("I received the message : " + message);
  return this;
})
```

It works but I get

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

(and the log message)

After that this code would be executed

```
.onMessageEquals("create a child", () -> {
  ActorRef<String> secondActor = getContext().spawn(FirstSimpleBehavior.create(),"second actor");
  secondActor.tell("who are you");
  return this;
})
```

But the console shows:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the method *spawn()* didn't accept my second argument, because it contained a space (I had missed that in the video). On the way a found that Logback already included slf4j ([link](https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-with-log4j2-logback)) so that (slf4j) I removed from the pom.

I fiddled with the pom so now the version of logback changed... But the pom is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>AkkaPrime2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <akka.version>2.6.8</akka.version>
    <scala.version>2.13</scala.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor-typed_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-testkit-typed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor-testkit-typed_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>${akka.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.9</version>
        <!--scope>test</scope-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

At baeldung.com there was no "scope" tag so I don't use (I don't know why to use it either).